# jQuery AJAX Customise showLoader

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Within the following jQuery **showLoader** can be set to show a loading icon while the AJAX request is made.

```
$.ajax({
  url: baseUrl,
  data: (paramData && paramData.length > 0 ? paramData + '&ajax=1' : 'ajax=1'),
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: true,
  showLoader: true,
  timeout: 10000
});
```

I want to know if there is a proper way to customise this to some html that i have set for loading icons to make loading icons uniform across my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can agree with Gopal, but be careful about handling errors. If the request fails, the loader should be hidden and user should be informed. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

The **complete** callback is better for this purpose, because it will be called anyway.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: ""
  beforeSend: function(){
       $(".show_load_icon").show();
  },
  complete: function(){
      $(".show_load_icon").hide();
  }
});
```

Or you can handle the error manually.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: ""
  beforeSend: function(){
       $(".show_load_icon").show();
  },
  success: function(){
      $(".show_load_icon").hide();
  },
  error: function(){
      $(".show_load_icon").hide();
      alert("Error"); // inform the user about error
  }
});
```

From jQuery 3.0 you can use .done() and .fail()

Answer (score 2):

For my suggestion there is no option for default ajax 
**showloader**

So you can go better for this way.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "someURL"
  data: "someDataString",
  beforeSend: function(msg){
       $(".show_load_icon").show();
  },
  success: function(msg){
      $(".show_load_icon").hide();
  }
});
```